# selectRowAtIndexPath on a UITableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I am trying to show a row in a UITableView as selected when the view appears. I am able to do this on a UIViewController, but when I try to do this on a UITableViewController, it does not work.

I am calling this in ViewDidAppear:

```
NSIndexPath *selectedIndex = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
[self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:selectedIndex animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
```

Is there a different way to achieve this inside a UITableViewController that will work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that the reason the table was not scrolling to the selected row was twofold.

Because I was selecting the row programmatically, and was using scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone. Using this, the table was not moving to the desired row. I changed it to scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop.

The other issue was that I was reloading the table view in ViewDidAppear. Changing that to ViewDidLoad made the difference in maintaining the selected row appearance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `selectedIndex` is nil, meaning there is no current row selected.

You need to keep track of the row you would like to select and then set it with `selectRowAtIndexPath:`

To verify that this works, try it with an existing row:

```
NSIndexPath *selectedIndex = [NSIndexPath indexForRow: 1 inSection: 0];
[self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:selectedIndex animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
```